# sql statement based on mulitple drop down selection

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I need to create an SQL statement that can adapt depending on what options are selected. I have 2 drop down lists being filled from a database.

Here is my ASP

```
<td class="theSearchTableData">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up_team" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl_team"></asp:DropDownList><%--AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_team_SelectedIndexChanged"--%>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>

                </td>
                <td class="theSearchTableData">
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl_owner"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                  <td class="theSearchTableData">
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl_actionowner" ></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
```

c# code

```
string Owner_ActionOwner_Combo = "";
string ownerClause = "";
string ActionownerClause = "";

    if (ddl_owner.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        ownerClause = " log_number in (SELECT DISTINCT log_number FROM Log_Data WHERE log_owner = @logOwner) AND ";
    }

    if (ddl_actionowner.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        ActionownerClause = " log_number in (SELECT DISTINCT log_number FROM Log_Data WHERE log_owner <> @actionOwner and current_action_owner = @actionOwner  ) AND ";
    }

    else if (ddl_actionowner.SelectedIndex >0 & ddl_owner.SelectedIndex > 0 )
    {
        Owner_ActionOwner_Combo = "log_number in (SELECT DISTINCT log_number FROM Log_Data WHERE current_action_owner = @actionOwner and log_owner =@logOwner) AND";
    }
string completeWhereClause = ActionownerClause + Owner_ActionOwner_Combo + ownerClause;
```

The '@' values have been parameterised.

The log_owner is usually the action_owner however there is a period of time where the log_owner is not the same as the action_owner. this is why i need to adapt the search criteria. 
if the user wants to know the log owner they search by log owner and the same as action owner. the problem is when  they search by both.

I have entered this into my database and get the correct numbers. For log_owner there are 32, if only action_owner there are 3 and for the combination there should be 24.

Thank you for your time

Comment: this doesnt seem necessary in the `ActionownerClause` `log_owner <> @actionOwner`

Comment: Can you specify in detail your problem?

Comment: @JamieD77 I am getting the logs that have the action owner but not the log owner. These two can be the same but can also be assigned to other people for a short period of time

Comment: @user449689 I have added more detail,

Comment: but why do you care who the log owner if they didnt actually select one from the list and only selected an action owner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way you have your if statement structured translates to this..

```
if (ddl_owner.SelectedIndex > 0)
{   Hit if ddl_owner.SelectedIndex > 0       }
if (ddl_actionowner.SelectedIndex > 0)
{   Hit if ddl_actionowner.SelectedIndex > 0       }
else if (ddl_actionowner.SelectedIndex > 0 & ddl_owner.SelectedIndex > 0)
{   Never hit        }
```

you probably should just move your combo if to the top and use else if for the other two

```
string Owner_ActionOwner_Combo = "";
string ownerClause = "";
string ActionownerClause = "";

if (ddl_actionowner.SelectedIndex > 0 && ddl_owner.SelectedIndex > 0)
{
    Owner_ActionOwner_Combo = "log_number in (SELECT DISTINCT log_number FROM Log_Data WHERE current_action_owner = @actionOwner and log_owner =@logOwner) AND";
}
else if (ddl_owner.SelectedIndex > 0)
{
    ownerClause = " log_number in (SELECT DISTINCT log_number FROM Log_Data WHERE log_owner = @logOwner) AND ";
}
else if (ddl_actionowner.SelectedIndex > 0)
{
    ActionownerClause = " log_number in (SELECT DISTINCT log_number FROM Log_Data WHERE current_action_owner = @actionOwner  ) AND ";
}
string completeWhereClause = ActionownerClause + Owner_ActionOwner_Combo + ownerClause;
```

Comment: Perfect! this has been bugging me for ages! Thank you very much!